# Determine if the stdout is terminal under ssh

Tags: perl, ssh, terminal, stdout

To test whether the output is terminal we can do `-t STDOUT`:

```
if (-t STDOUT) {
  # print with terminal control chars
} else {
  # just plain print
}
```

But when the script is executed in the ssh session not run from terminal (Jenkins in my case), the `-t` test still returns true and my output gets polluted with control chars:

```
ssh user@server "/my/script.pl"
```

Why does the `-t` detects the terminal?

Comment: It would appear that `-t` cannot distinguish between a "real" terminal and the pseudo terminal created by the `ssh` session on the remote end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know *why* ssh is allocating a terminal for you — mine defaults to not doing that even if the output of `ssh` goes to a terminal — but passing `-T` to ssh will disable pseudo-tty creation on the remote end.

```
$ ssh -t localhost "perl -E'say -t STDOUT ?1:0'"
1
Connection to localhost closed.

$ ssh -T localhost "perl -E'say -t STDOUT ?1:0'"
0
```

From `ssh`'s man page:

> `-T`  Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
>
> `-t` Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary
>          screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful,
>          e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty
>          allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good advice. Indeed, the -t returns false for ssh. The offender turned out to be Log::Log4perl::Appender::ScreenColoredLevels appender for Log::Log4perl which does not pay attention to the -t flag. Sounds like a patch.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better if you instead forced ssh to allocate a pty —

From the `ssh` manual:

> `-t` Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs
>   on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.
>   Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

The longer answer: `-t` (the Perl or Bourne shell function) reliably detects whether the stream is a “typewriter,” but `ssh` will normally only allocate a pseudo-teletype (`pty`) stream in interactive shells, not when other programs are being started.

See also `RequestTTY` as an option in `.ssh/config`.